# Render recursive structures - unclosed tag error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, htmlbars

I have some problems rendering dropdown menu with Ember.js and HtmlBars.
Data I have for menu is in array, something like this:

```
[{name: 'A', lvl: 0}, {name: 'B', lvl: 1}, {name: 'C', lvl: 0}, {name: 'D', lvl: 1}, , {name: 'E', lvl: 1}]
```

which should result in following html

```
<ul>
  <li> <a> A </a> 
    <ul>
      <li> <a> B </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a> C </a> 
    <ul>
      <li> <a> D </a> </li>
      <li> <a> E </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and it would have following structure(with css it will become nice dropdown)

- A

  - B
- C

  - D
  - E

The problem is that HTMLbars does not allow following structures

```
{{#if (condition1)}}
  <ul class="d-menu" data-role="dropdown">
{{/if}}

{{#if (condition2)}}
  </ul>
{{/if}}
```

Now, I am aware that this is not a bug, but project decision, but I am unsure how to overcome that limitation and to do what I need? The only option I currently see is to generate html string in js code, as I am not allowed to change data model format. If it is possible to replace HTMLbars with something different, it would be acceptable solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your data to something like this:

```
[{
  name: 'A', 
  children: [ {name: 'B'} ]
}, {
  name: 'C', 
  children: [{name: 'D'} , {name: 'E'}]
}]
```

it would be easier to handle, because then you can have a `component` called, for example `component-x` that do something like:

```
 <ul>
    {{#each menuArray as |item|}}
      {{#if item.children}}
        <li><a>{{item.name}}</a> {{component-x name=item.name menuArray=item.children}}</li>
      {{else}}
         <li><a>{{item.name}}</a></li>
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Henry. However, this would be the solution if I could change the data, but as I wrote in my question, I can't, as it is used in some other places also. Also, the number of levels is indefinite, so it would then had to be done with recursion, and I am looking for iterative solution.

Comment: What about transforming your data? if it's that simple, it won't be difficult to change it internally in a component and keep it the same outside for other purposes.